# ABAP syntax error during generation of Adobe form

Tags: adobe, abap

Thats the following error that I face now . Its a kind of error that happens on the standard SAP side . I'm unable to find where the field 'vbrk' is . 
Any solution ?

The following syntax error occurred in program "/1BCDWB/SAPLSM00001494 " in
  include "/1BCDWB/LSM00001494F01 " in
 line 717:
 "The field "VBRK" is unknown, but there is a field with the similar name"
  "GS_VBRK" . . . ."

Comment: Could you please copy the respective line (#717) here? The system generates a function module from the adobe form, that will be /1BCDWB/SAPLSM00001494. The error is in include /1BCDWB/LSM00001494F01, you can display that in SE38 and navigate to line 717.

Comment: 716 .PERFORM %OUTPUT USING 'MWSBP' %WORKAREA1-MWSBP 'CURR' 'P' 'VBRK-WAERK' VBRK-WAERK ' '.
717.PERFORM %OUTPUT USING 'GV_PRICE' GV_PRICE 'CURR' 'P' ' ' ' ' ' '.

Comment: Ok, it's brief the code you posted but you are using as argument a parameter 'VBRK-WAERK', try using GS_VBRK-WAERK. I'm based on the original error. If it not works please post more code.

Comment: I believe the data binding is not correct somewhere in the form. A  field on the form is linked to VBRK-WAERK instead of (probably) GS_VBRK-WAERK. Check the interface of the form as well, how the data is defined there (it is probably GS_VBRK)

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'VBRK' is a table. It contents the 'Billing Document: Header Data'.

According to the brief description you made, it seems like you are specifying a wrong parameter.

> "The field "VBRK" is unknown, but there is a field with the similar
>   name" "GS_VBRK" . . . ."